# Allure report: list of tests without grouping

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, testng, allure

I need to have a list of all tests in Allure report without grouping by error message, suites, packages, etc. Like this:

[nice to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYeDC.png)

Tried to use categories.json in allure-results folder:

```
[ 
   { 
     "name": "List of all tests", 
     "mathedStatuses": ["broken", "failed", "skipped", "passed"] 
   } 
]
```

but Allure groups tests by error:

[Allure's grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaUQe.png)

Env: java11, gradle, testNg, Allure 2.20.1

Thanks in advance!

ps: chatGpt is NOT helpful at all))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of a typo in "mathedStatuses"? You should use:

```
[ 
   { 
     "name": "List of all tests", 
     "matchedStatuses": ["broken", "failed", "skipped", "passed"] 
   } 
]
```